# Firestore rule to read collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Firestore rule to read collection overrides document rule to deny unauthorized access of other users data.

Here's my scenario, I'm getting the user information with the phone number associated by the Authentication and the Document in the database. I'm querying the whole ***/users*** collection with ***where*** clause and in the Firestore Rules I'm letting anyone to read ***/users*** collection, but I think this is insecure.

Javascript

```
const phone_number = firebase.auth().currentUser.phoneNumber // Example: "+5521988887777"
const usersRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users')

usersRef.where("phone_number", "==", phone_number).limit(1).get()
  .then(snapshot => {
    const doc = snapshot.docs[0]
```

Firestore Rules

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users {
      allow read;
    }
    match /users/{user} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.token.phone_number == resource.data.phone_number;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to achieve a workaround to the issue, thanks.

Comment: the first `match /users` allows public read access, right? Don't you want to remove that?

Comment: But without that I'm unable to query the collection with where

Comment: I think I understand now, if just one of the query result isn't allowed, the whole request is denied, right?

Comment: The default access (empty rules file) is disallow any/all.

Comment: @ViniciusFontoura you should be able to query several documents, as long as each one is allowed by the read security rule. This seems to be the case, since both the security rule and the query use the phone_number. So I think you could remove the first condition to allow all reads.

Comment: @RicardoSmania Thanks, perfect explanation, I was anxious and did not waited the 10 minutes to update the rule. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To correct the security rule I have removed the first condition to allow all reads (as commented above).

Working Firestore Rules

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{user} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.token.phone_number == resource.data.phone_number;
    }
  }
}
```